# file permission of an image

Tags: php

In my PHP web server I have written PHP code to upload an image to the server. I have created both thumbnail images. While displaying the image the thumbnail is not displaying. But the actual image is displaying properly. I have checked the server. Here the permission of thumbnail is 640. I want to make it to 777.  I have set 777 permission to the folder, which contain the thumb image).

Does any one know this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `chmod` function right after creating the thumbnail image:

```
chmod($thumbnailFile, 0666);
```

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: there is no reason in executing images.

Comment: +1 for not using `0777`. Edit: oh, that was an edit. You had `0777`. -1.

Comment: and even modifying is not needed! `0644` is far enough

Answer (score 2):

0) 777 is almost certainly wrong. Don't use 777. For example, there's no sane reason to even have the 'execute' bit on for images that I can think of. You also probably don't want the thumbnails to be 'writable' by users other than the one creating it. My best guess is that you really just wanted 'user readable, user writable, world readable': 0644

1) Set the umask() before creating the image, so that the resulting file has the correct permissions. See php.net/umask - assuming you want the aforementioned 'user readable, user writable, world readable', you'd want your umask() to be set to something like 0033.

Even if that's not actually the mode you wanted, umask() should still get you headed the correct direction - but I'd urge you to consider granting the LEAST permissions possible to do the required task, it just makes everything easier.

Comment: However, 777 is the only choice for directories on most shared hostings. And it seems the OP is on one of that kind. So, 666 for the file, as it's anyway would be accessible from others even with 644